# In OpenCL what is the difference between threads and workitems?

Tags: opencl

I am a little bit confused on threads vs workitems. Are there any difference between the two?
I understand the unit of execution on the GPU Cores is workgroup, which consist of workitems. Is this not same as threads?

Answer (score 3):

The terms 'threads' and 'cores' differ depending on the hardware you are running on. On NVIDIA hardware, a work-item is equivalent to a 'CUDA thread'. On CPUs, a thread usually executes an entire work-group, with individual work-items being packed into SIMD lanes.

So when talking about OpenCL programs, it's best to stick to the terms 'work-item', 'work-group', 'compute unit' and 'processing element', to avoid these naming issues.